# How to setfacl on a directory and all its parents?

Tags: acl, setfacl

Let's say we have the following directory structure

```
a
  b1
    c1
    c2
  b2
    c3
    c4
```

And I want to use setfacl to give a user frank access to c1, I can do something like

`setfacl -m u:frank:rX a/b1/c1`

However this doesn't give him access to a and b1 automatically.

The -R option does solve this because it applies the ACL to c1's children if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the list of directories you want the ACLs applied to, that's the same for all commands that can modify file metadata like `chown`, `chmod`, `chattr`, `setfattr`, `touch` whether they have recursive mode of operations or not... Here, you'd also want to make sure none of the path components are symlinks.

So:

```
setfacl -m u:frank:rX a a/b1 a/b1/c1
```

Or in shells with support for csh-like brace expansion:

```
setfacl -m u:frank:rX a{,/b1{,/c1}}
```

If your shell is `zsh`, you can define a function like:

```
upward() until [[ $argv[-1] = . ]] { "$@"; argv[-1]=$argv[-1]:h; }
```

Then:

```
$ upward echo setfacl -m u:frank:rX a/b1/c1
setfacl -m u:frank:rX a/b1/c1
setfacl -m u:frank:rX a/b1
setfacl -m u:frank:rX a
```

(remove the `echo` to actually run `setfacl`).

Or you could define a:

```
ancestry() until [[ $REPLY = . ]] { reply+=($REPLY); REPLY=$REPLY:h; }
```

function to be used as a glob qualifier:

```
$ echo setfacl -m u:frank:rX a/b1/c1(+ancestry)
setfacl -m u:frank:rX a a/b1 a/b1/c1
```

Or for a `d`epth-first `o`rder:

```
$ echo setfacl -m u:frank:rX a/b1/c1(od+ancestry)
setfacl -m u:frank:rX a/b1/c1 a/b1 a
```

In any case, note that as soon as you grand `frank` search access to `a`, that may open up his access to `a/b2` if that directory access wasn't restricted on the ground that access was restricted above.

Comment: Thx. So basically you have to apply the ACL layer by layer?

Comment: @DrizzleX, yes you need to specify the files to which the ACLs are to be applied to. See edit.